# How to check if IMobileServiceTableQuery<T> is empty or not

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin

I want to check if a value exists in my Easy Tables Azure database before inserting it.

```
var l = App.MobileService.GetTable<User>().Where(u => u.email == user.email)
```

When I then try to turn the IMobileServiceTableQuery, `l` into a list I get a NullReferenceException

```
if(l == null)
{

}
else{
     var list = await l.ToListAsync();
     await App.MobileService.GetTable<User>().InsertAsync(user);
}
```

When I try the following:

```
var l = App.MobileService.GetTable<User>().Where(u => u.email == user.email);
        if(l.Query == null)
        {

        }
        else{
            // var list = await l.ToListAsync();
            if(l.Query.Count() == 0)
            {
                await App.MobileService.GetTable<User>().InsertAsync(user);
            }
        }
```

...The insert is made each time I run the code. Meaning the `l.Query.Count()` is always 0.

How can see and check if IMobileServiceTableQuery is empty or not?

Comment: Is it possible that the C# class User has non-nullable properties? Perhaps one of the records in your database is trying to bind a null to a non-nullable property when it gets the results from the database.

Comment: I can get a valid list of users when running the app. But not with my unit test. So there seems to be a problem with the unit test

Comment: I had to change the async method return type to `Task<bool>` instead of `void` to successfully run it with the unit test